# Populating cells based on thresholds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to populate a table using the same columns and data from a data source with an identical table based on a <30% or >70% threshold.

EX:

| Store # | % change |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 28% |
| 9 | 75% |

Data Source Table

| Store # | % change |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 28% |
| 9 | 75% |
| 14 | 54% |
| 23 | 62% |

Stores 3 & 9 were populated in because 3 is under 30%, and 9 is over 70%.

Answer (score 2):

E2  =FILTER(A2:B5;(B2:B5<0,3)+(B2:B5>0,7))

[image]

When your criteria are in a different range or sheet, you need this:

[image]

```
A24 =FILTER(HSTACK(A13:A16;L17:L20);(Sheet35!L17:L20<0,3)+(Sheet35!L17:L20>0,7))
```

Always make sure that all ranges in the formula have the same size (same amount of rows).

Comment: I tried using the following for the filter but it did not work: 
Table 1 is the source, Column M is where the percentage lies. 
=FILTER(Table1;(Sheet2!M:M<0.3)+(Sheet2!M:M<0.7))

Comment: You could do this in a single step without the lookup by doing `E2 = FILTER(A2:B5;(B2:B5<0,3)+(B2:B5>0,7))`

Comment: @WeAreOne if someone has access to HSTACK() then they also have access to XLOOKUP(), eliminating the need for added step of stacking.

Comment: @WeAreOne Well, there's more then...  You can still eliminate the second step of doing the LOOKUP() by doing an HSTACK() **first** so when you apply the filter, you are filtering columns that are already adjacent:  `=FILTER(HSTACK(A13:A16;L17:L20);(Sheet35!L17:L20<0,3)+(Sheet35!L17:L20>0,7))` gets it all done in one formula.

Comment: @max R 
Sorry my dyslexic brain cant understand what im doing wrong here. When i try to replace your referenced cells with mine, it keeps giving me errors.

=FILTER(table1(date);(Sheet1!D:D<0,3)+(Sheet1!D:D>0,7))
Table 1 and column D are on the same sheet, separate from where i want the data pulled into.
Column D is the column with the percentages.

Comment: @jlee3416 as I wrote earlier, the amount of rows need to be the same. What is "table1(date)”???? It should be a range there. If you use a named range, make sure it is the same size as the other ranges in the formula. That is the mistake.  I guess you can't use D:D as range, because table1 might not be a whole column. You could upload a picture of your sample data

Comment: @weareone 
it seems that I am running into an issue when i try to replace the (A13:16;L17:L20) referenced cells with my data, it gives me the error code. As soon as I replace the A Cells with what I have, and then try to click in to replace the L cells it kicks me back to the formula with an error message. I tried uploading pictures but it wouldnt let me.

Comment: @jlee3416 inserting pictures in the questing is just copying and pasting. What are you trying to write instead of A13:A16?

Comment: @jlee3416 also you might need to replace the argument separator semicolon with a comma, if your Excel version usually uses comma. That might the reson for the instant error when you try to replace the cell references

Comment: @WeAreOne

i think the screenshot is too much data and I dont think pieces of the page will help. 
I'm trying to replce A13:A16 with either Table1{date} or Sheet2A:A which is the same column as date